# Plotting dates in python graphs

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have an array of dates in the format ('yyyy-mm-dd') and another array of integers numbers, each corresponding to a value in the date array. But, when I tried to plot the graph using:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(dates, values, label='Price')
```

It gives the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2017-07-26'
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your dates are strings, convert them to datetime objects first.

```
import datetime
x = [datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d") for date in dates]
```

Comment: I did what you told me to do but the error remains. If you want to review my code here's a link: https://pastebin.com/RuiYWY1B ,and here's the format of the external file : https://pastebin.com/5hDAuXLE

Comment: What's the output of `type(dates[0])` and `type(x[0])` ?

Comment: I tried and couldn't do that. It keeps giving me the same error